# Including data with SYN-ACK on Linux

Tags: linux, tcp

[TCP Fast Open](https://lwn.net/Articles/508865/) seems to be well-defined and fully(?) implemented in Linux. The API is really clear for including data in the SYN, and I can see that working on wire with no problem.

How do I include data in the SYN-ACK, though? The protocol specifically allows it when there was a valid cookie in the SYN (since we've verified the client). However, accept() seems to send the SYN-ACK immediately without anything like Nagle, so there's no chance for a send() after accept() to get merged into one packet. There doesn't seem be an alternative accept() API (a server-side equivalent to the connect() -> sendto() client migration). Does the API just not allow for this?

Comment: Section "The user-space API" in [this article from LWN](https://lwn.net/Articles/508865/) might help.

Comment: That's the same article that I linked to. It shows how to set the socket option on the server side to indicate willingness to accept data in the SYN, but doesn't mention how to include data in the response.

Comment: You are right. Given the figure 3 in the article I think the current API does not support sending data together with SYN_ACK, but it supports sending data before it gets the clients ACK to the servers SYN since the accept call will already return to user space once it received the initial SYN with the cookie.